# Rails: order items in nested view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model called Post which belongs_to another model named Group.  So currently a user can navigate to a group and create a post, the post is displayed under the correct view.  However, I'm trying to figure out how to make the posts display in descending order so that the newest post is on top for that particular group.

this is in the posts_controller.  It places them in descending order correctly when I go to .../groups/:id/posts however I need the posts to display descending in .../groups/:id

```
   # GET /groups/:group_id/posts
    def index
      @posts = @group.posts.order("created_at desc")
    end
```

This is in the groups/show.html.erb view.  Is there a way to add a descending order onto `@group.posts.each` ?

```
      <%= link_to 'New Post', new_group_post_path(@group.id) %>  
      <!-- gets posts for the group -->
      <div class="row">
          <% @group.posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="card bottom-pad">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title"><%= link_to post.title, group_post_path(@group, post), class: "text-primary" %></h4>
              <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(post.content, length: 500)   %><br><br>
               <%= post.user.last_name %>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <small class="text-muted"><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) + " ago" %></small>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br><br>
        </div><!--./col-->
        <% end %><!--./@group.posts.each-->
      </div><!--./row-->
```

Comment: Why not just `@group.posts.order(created_at: :desc).each do |post|` in your `show.html.erb`?

Comment: ah ok that's what I was looking for, works good.  If you want to make it an answer I'll mark it as correct if you want the points.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the ordering in your `show.html.erb` like this:

```
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_group_post_path(@group.id) %>  
<!-- gets posts for the group -->
<div class="row">
  <% @group.posts.order(created_at: :desc).each do |post| %>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card bottom-pad">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"><%= link_to post.title, group_post_path(@group, post), class: "text-primary" %></h4>
          <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(post.content, length: 500)   %><br><br>
           <%= post.user.last_name %>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted"><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) + " ago" %></small>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
    </div><!--./col-->
  <% end %><!--./@group.posts.each-->
</div><!--./row-->
```